# How to make re.split() inclusive

Tags: python, regex

I have the following:

```
>>> x='STARSHIP_TROOPERS_INVASION_2012_LOCDE'
>>> re.split('_\d{4}',x)[0]
'STARSHIP_TROOPERS_INVASION'
```

How would I get the year included? For example:

```
STARSHIP_TROOPERS_INVASION_2012
```

Note there are tens of thousands of titles, and I need to split on the year for each. I can't do a normal python `split()` here.

Comment: Do you really need `split`? It's not clear from your example. You can probably get what you need with `re.findall` or (judging by your sample) just `re.match`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A more straightforward solution](http://ideone.com/aq0XiL) would be using [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search)/[`MatchObject.end()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.end):

```
m = re.search('_\d{4}', x)
print x[:m.end(0)]
```

If you want to stick with `split()`, you can [use a lookbehind](http://ideone.com/gE9PPA):

```
re.split('(?<=_\d{4}).', x)
```

(This work even when the year is at the end of the string, because `split()` returns an array with the original string in case the delimiter isn't found.)

Comment: I like the lookbehind, but I think `re` may be overkill here. +1 from me nonetheless.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It might but I'd rather not make assumptions about what the OP is trying to do from a single input string.

Answer (score 3):

If its always going to be the same pattern, then why not:

```
>>> x = 'STARSHIP_TROOPERS_INVASION_2012_LOCDE'
>>> x[:x.rfind('_')]
'STARSHIP_TROOPERS_INVASION_2012'
```

For your original regular expression, since you aren't capturing the matched group, it is not part of your matches:

```
>>> re.split('_\d{4}',x)
['STARSHIP_TROOPERS_INVASION', '_LOCDE']
>>> re.split('_(\d{4})',x)
['STARSHIP_TROOPERS_INVASION', '2012', '_LOCDE']
```

The `()` marks the selection as a [captured group](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and
>   indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group can be
>   retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched later
>   in the string with the \number special sequence, described below. To
>   match the literals '(' or ')', use ( or ), or enclose them inside a
>   character class: [(] [)].

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. What does the `()` around the `\d{4}` do?

Comment: It makes it part of the captured group that is returned.

Comment: Hm, I wasn't even aware `re.split()` has different behaviour if you use capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

you may use both `split()` and `search()` supposing you have a single such date in your string you wish to split at.

```
import re
x='STARSHIP_TROOPERS_INVASION_2012_LOCDE'
date=re.search('_\d{4}',x).group(0)
print(date)
```

gives

```
>>> 
_2012
```

and

```
print(re.split('_\d{4}',x)[0]+date)
```

gives

```
STARSHIP_TROOPERS_INVASION_2012
```